# Python: Split a string, respect brackets

Tags: python, split, brackets

I'm trying to split something like the following string

```
s = '1 2 3 {test 0, test 0} {test 0 test 0}'
```

what I'm trying to get is

```
['1', '2', '3', '{test 0, test 0}', '{test 0, test 0}']
```

or

```
['1', '2', '3', 'test 0, test 0', 'test 0, test 0']
```

Could someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\s(?![^{]*})
```

Split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/4

```
re.split(r"\s(?![^{]*})",s)
```

Or

```
print re.split(r"\s(?![^{]*})|{|}",s)
```

If you dont want `{}` as well.

Explanation:\s `space`

`(?![^{]*})` negative lookahead stating after space there should not be `}` which has no `{` before it.

So this way `{test 0 test 0}` the space after `0` will not be considered as it has `}` ahead wihtout `{`.

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of the regular expression you chose. Sure we can search this by ourselves, but it would make your answer much more precise :)

Comment: `['1', '2', '3', '', 'test 0, test 0', '', '', 'test 0 test 0', '']` doesn't match op's desired output

Comment: @jamylak if you are talking about the `,` between second `test` that is a typo by OP.Else reast is same

Comment: If OP has nested brackets, this won't correctly handle them.  But in that case you can't use regexes anyway.

Comment: @Kevin yes that would require recursion which is not supported by python